# if-statement always takes the true path, unless we move the interior to its own method

Tags: c#, iis

I have some code that gets a `Checkpoint` object, and we check if it has a value, throw an exception if it doesn't.  However, whatever value is in version, it always throws the exception.

```
if (!mostRecentCheckpoint.Version.HasValue) 
{
    throw new ApplicationException(
    string.Format("Invalid version of {0} Checkpoint not found for the case {1}",
    CaseProductDataCheckpointType.CurrentActive, caseId));
}
```

if we replace the exception with a method, though, it does the right thing:

```
if (!mostRecentCheckpoint.Version.HasValue) 
{
    ThrowException(caseId);
}
...
void ThrowException(int caseId) 
{
    throw new ApplicationException( etc...)
}
```

Which is great, because we've solved the problem, but I want to know why it does this.  I don't know if it's relevant, but this code runs in IIS -- unit tests of the code act correctly.

Comment: The code you provided should not change the behavior. Are you sure you made no other changes to the code between the two versions you posted. For example you never tested your 2nd version on the same IIS server?

Comment: I agree with Scott's comment, and I'll go one further and suggest that it's simply not possible that the only differences between the two scenarios are correctly represented here. Please provide a concise and _complete_ code example that reproduces the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That really is the only difference between the working and the not-working code.  (I do know how to use a diff tool).  It's because the behavior is so baffling that I posted the question.  I believe that the issue is in the way the code is executed in IIS, because unit tests run successfully.  I will work on a reproducer, but I was hoping this was actually a known weirdness in iis

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this problem occurs because of an issue in the VS2010 debugger.

http://whileicompile.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/visual-studio-bug-if-followed-by-a-try-catch-causes-debugger-stepping-error/

I'll leave this here in case anyone else has the same problem.